# azure-storage not working with web pack (azure-functions-pack) server side

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, azure-storage, azure-functions

I made an Azure Function micro service using Node.js and I'm using the npm module azure-storage to insert files in a Blob Storage.

Locally is working fine, but when deploying to development environment, it is executed a script that executes azure-functions-pack and generate a bundle with the service code and all the required npm modules. Then when making a request to the micro service, it return a status code 500 and in the logs the error is the following:

> ```
> System.Exception : Error: Cannot find module "."
> at webpackMissingModule (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:238044:68)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:238044:147)
> at __webpack_require__ (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:21:30)
> ...
> ```

I only know that the problem is the azure-storage module because If I comment the "azureStorage = require('azure-storage');" , then start working. I also tried the npm module fast-azure-storage without success and until now I was not able to find a workaround for this problem. The code that uses this module is the following:

```
    const blobSvc = azureStorage.createBlobService(storageConnectionString);
    const writeStream = blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('containerName', fileName);

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      writeStream.write(svgString);
      writeStream.on('close', () => {
        resolve('https://' + storageAccount + '.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/' + fileName);
      });

      writeStream.end();
    });
```

The version of azure-storage is 2.6.0. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question - but you should use output binding feature of Azure Function to insert Blobs instead of doing that manually with library calls.

If you do that, you won't have to import the package, so it will also solve your problem.

Read more about output bindings in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob), there is a node example there too.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for the response. The solution that you propose might be part of the solution, and I did that change, but right now funcpack seems to change the type of some variables which causes some errors. This is strange because we have a lot of micro services using funcpack and everything is working fine. Just in this case causes problems, but I'm working on it and when I find the solution I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mikhail. Unfortunately in our case, the blob storage binding doesn't seem to be the best choice because we need to send the name of the Blob to the user before the service is done and the blob name is only generated after the service is done. In the case of C# is possible in the code to bind a variable to the blob name, and in that case it would be a good solution. Unfortunately in Node.js, that seems to not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem wasn't the azure-storage module, but the node-chartist module which for some reason also was causing problems in other modules. After remove node-chartist all the modules started working perfectly.